# django parse Response header X-Auth

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

```
cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT User.name,Person.id,Person.firstName,Person.lastName,User.tokenHash from User JOIN Person ON User.personId = Parkloco.Person.id WHERE User.name = '%s' AND User.enabled = 1 " % username)
fields = map(lambda x: x[0], cursor.description)
result = [dict(zip(fields, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
Response['X-Auth'] = result.tokenHash
return Response(result,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

How to Parse Response Header in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always send headers in Response as an argument and pass the header object like this

```
header = { X-Auth: result.tokenHash }
return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=header)
```

Also you can get more information about the Django Response [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/).

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: but it should be like this.Thanks for the answer.
header = { 'X-Auth': result.tokenHash }
return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=header)